# Websphere App server [WARNING ] CWWKC0044W and [WARNING ] CWWKC0022W:

Tags: java, servlets, websphere-liberty

Running Websphere App server V8.5 Liberty Profile. I've failed to find any help that can resolve these warnings. I'm on eclipse.

```
        **************   Here's my servlet code ************
        package com.rocketsoft.zoskmip.kmipuser;

        import java.io.IOException;
        import java.io.PrintWriter;
        import javax.servlet.ServletException;
        import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
        import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
        import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
        import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
         /**
         * Servlet implementation class AddUser
         */
        @WebServlet("/user")
        public class AddUser extends HttpServlet {
     private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

         public AddUser() {
    super();
}
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
       throws ServletException, IOException {
    PrintWriter printWriter = response.getWriter();
    printWriter.print("Welcome");
    String firstName = request.getParameter("fname");
    printWriter.print(firstName);
}
}
```

**********WARNINGS***************

> [WARNING ] CWWKC0044W: An exception occurred while scanning class and annotation data. The exception was {0}.
>
> [WARNING ] CWWKC0022W: [ com.ibm.ws.anno.info.internal.ClassInfoCache@957735840 ] The scan of class [java.lang.Object] caused an exception. The message is: [Class [ java.lang.Object ] from resource [ java/lang/Object.class ] Exception creating reader] caused by [null].

Comment: Which JDK version are you using?

Comment: 1.8.0_05  I'm running java7

Comment: 1.8.0_05 is a Java 8 SDK :) 1.7.x is Java 7.

Comment: Ohh right! Thanks a bunch Dirk! Let me go back to 7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The warnings look very much like you're trying to run Liberty Profile under Java8.

[Liberty profile does not (yet) support Java8](https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/9342/support-for-java-8/), so as far as I know your only current supported option is to go back to Java7.

Comment: My system is running Java7, unless my eclipse IDE has something else installed. I just tried looking it up and the only thing i got was that JEE is v2.2.. Any ways to look it up? or where can i change it from? Thanks for the help J.

Comment: This post also save us. We are using WASLP8.5, locally on Windows works great with IBM JDK 1.8, but on Linux enviornment it requires Java7, very strange.